# Installing ubuntu on a separate hard drive

Tags: 18.04, windows-10

so my laptop has two hard drives, the first one already has windows 10 installed, i want to install ubuntu on the second one, my question is, will that cause any problems after installing ubuntu ? can i boot into windows 10 normally without any issues ?

Comment: Most new UEFI systems have a UEFI setting to disable a drive. So you do not have to physically disconnect a drive. Standard install to second drive with Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer puts grub boot files into first drive's ESP, usually Windows' ESP. And that does work unless you must boot the second drive if external. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Ubiquity wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i just booted  normally to the usb installer and proceeded to install ubuntu to the second drive without any issues, so now if i want to boot into ubuntu i just hit escape key upon starting, i choose to boot from my second drive and voila! 
to boot into windows i just boot normally without any intervention! thank you guys for the help.